# Are there any mantras for each of the twelve jyotirlingas

Tags: mantras, shiva-purana, manuscripts, jyotirlinga, shivadvaita

Are there any specific japa mantras for each of the twelve jyotirlingas? Are they mentioned in any sacred text?

Comment: Dwadasa Jyotirlinga Stotram? 

A prayer addressed to the 12 Jyotirlingas of Bhagwan Shiva. It was composed by Sri Adi Shankaracharya.


Here u can listen to stotram https://youtu.be/QgkBIoUeAa0